# Signal and Slot understanding in Qt

Tags: qt

I am having problem with "Signal and Slot" understanding. Here below is my task description.

1. Select an item from Combo Box
2. Display that selected item, by a Label in the `mainwindow`.

It is very simple thing but I am not able to solve it.

Here below is my code:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void activated(QString);

private slots:
     void setLabelValue(const QString &text);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->comboBox, &QComboBox::activated(QString),
            this, &MainWindow::setLabelValue(QString));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

MainWindow::setLabelValue(const QString &text)
{
    //text = ui->comboBox->currentText();
text = static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(QString)>(ui->comboBox->currentText());
    ui->label->setText(text);
}
```

I hope you will forgive this novice's coding and understanding style.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you need to use the `QLabel` accessor function to change the text value. `text()` is a 'getter', not a 'setter'.

change `MainWindow::setLabelValue()` to

```
MainWindow::setLabelValue()
{
    ui->label->setText(ui->comboBox->currentText());
}
```

Also, your connection isn't quite right. `setLabelValue` is a function of `MainWindow`, not the label, so change the connection to:

```
void (QComboBox::* activatedOverloadPtr)(const QString&) = &QComboBox::activated;
connect(ui->comboBox,activatedOverloadPointer, this, &MainWindow::setLabelValue);
```

Activated overload pointer is used so that the compiler can resolve which specific `activated` connection you are looking for.

The complete code would look something like:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

//signals: // this is defined by QComboBox, not you (in this case)
//    void activated(QString);

private slots:
     void setLabelValue(const QString &text);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    void (QComboBox::* activatedOverloadPtr)(const QString&) = &QComboBox::activated;
    connect(ui->comboBox,activatedOverloadPointer, this, &MainWindow::setLabelValue);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

MainWindow::setLabelValue()
{
    ui->label->setText(ui->comboBox->currentText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed but its still not working and showing some errors.

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->comboBox,&QComboBox::activated,ui->label,&QLabel::setLabelValue);
}

MainWindow::setLabelValue()

{
    ui->label->setText(ui->comboBox->currentText());

}

Comment: @eklavay.tonoy I updated the answer, your connection wasn't quite right after all.

Comment: Thanks really a lot. But I am still unsuccessful to achieve what I want. Having the following errors:
 cpp:11: error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection Object::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'overloaded-function' to 'const char *' Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function

Comment: @eklavay.tonoy we'll need to see the whole code, including the header to figure that out. update your question.

Comment: @ Nicolas Holthaus, followed your suggestion but still errors are there.
  
error: C2065: 'activatedOverloadPointer' : undeclared identifier
error: C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'QString' to 'void (__cdecl QComboBox::* )(QString)'

Eventhough didnt work: to avoid error also tried the modified slot, to ensure that text will get a QString value: 
 
MainWindow::setLabelValue(const QString &text)
{     
    text = static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(QString)>(ui->comboBox->currentText());
    ui->label->setText(text);
}

Comment: yeah... you didn't do what the answer told you to do. why would you try to static_cast a function pointer to a QString. I'll update with a more precise version of what I meant, but seriously I think you're going to have a hard time with Qt until you brush up on your c++ skills.

Comment: @ Nicolas Holthaus, I also follow you. So I am trying to not only brush up but also learing it seriously. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for your support. Here below the code, that has worked.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
     void setLabelValue(const QString &text);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->comboBox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(const QString&)>(&QComboBox::activated), this,
            &MainWindow::setLabelValue);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setLabelValue(const QString &text)
{
    ui->label->setText(text);
}
```